# »Business als usual«, »business as usual« or... What's the preferred form?

Tags: expression, capitalization, loanword, quotes

As it turns out, there are many variations of writing *business as usual* in German. I’m quoting below four sentences containing the expression, three of them come from German newspapers and one from the website of the European Parliament. Are some of the below ways of writing *business as usual* preferable to others?

- [Frankfurter Allgemeine](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/brexit/nach-brexit-referendum-neue-wucht-des-nationalismus-14305755.html):

  > Ein **business as usual** kann es aber auf keinen Fall mehr geben.
- [Taz.de](http://taz.de/Umgang-mit-intersexuellen-Kindern/!5361693/):

  > Dafür zu sorgen, dass diese menschenrechtsverletzenden Eingriffe beendet werden, erfordert mehr als Beratung und das Vertrauen auf die Selbstregelung der Ärzteschaft – gerade wenn man die Beweise präsentiert bekommen hat, dass letztere unter anderem Label **Business als usual** machen.
- [Süddeutsche Zeitung](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/politik/international-nato-und-russland-sprechen-wieder-miteinander-dpa.urn-newsml-dpa-com-20090101-160408-99-510188):

  > Gleichzeitig sei aber klar, dass es keine Rückkehr zum **"business as usual"** geben werde, solange Russland sich nicht an internationales Recht halte.
- [Website of the European Parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT%20CRE%2020110608%20ITEM-003%20DOC%20XML%20V0//DE):

  > Der aktuelle Haushaltsplan ist viel zu sehr **„Business as usual“**.

Comment: The taz "als" is a typo imho, so your question boils down to "should an English noun be capitalized according to the German rules" and "should quotation marks be used".

Comment: Or "usual" is a typo. May be "usuell" was intended.

Comment: @Eugene Str,  'as'  and 'als' are easily mixed up. Especially when the automatic spelling check of the text is actually for German. I don't think, that they wanted to write 'business als usuell'. A German replacement were 'das Geschäft/alles geht seinen Gang'.

Comment: @EugeneStr.: Unlikely, because *als* is a mistranslation - in this context, *as* should be translated as *wie*. On top of that, *usuell* is an extremely uncommon word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/business_as_usual) sagt, man schreibe es klein.

Das ist auch einigermassen naheliegend, der Begriff ist ein vollständiges englisches Zitat und kein Lehnwort - Von daher entspricht die Orthographie vollständig dem englischen Original. Ein Zitat wird auch üblicherweise in Anführungszeichen gesetzt, so wie auch in einigen deiner Beispiele.

Wäre der Ausdruck hinreichend eingedeutscht und in die deutsche Sprache übernommen, kämen auch die deutschen Groß- Kleinschreibungsregeln zu Einsatz. Das ist hier aber wohl (noch) nicht der Fall (Das Weglassen der Anführungszeichen bei taz und FAZ deutet aber schon in diese Richtung, dann ist aber m.A. nach die Kleinschreibung, so wie sie die FAZ verwendet, falsch)

Comment: Schreibst Du noch was über die Anführungszeichen?

Answer (score 0):

Mit Anführungsstrichen ist falsch bzw. stilistisch schlecht.

Anführungsstriche werden um direkte Rede gesetzt und um Zitate. Eine einzelne Phrase ist aber niemals ein Zitat. Auch wenn ein Redner einen Ausdruck, den man in indirekter Rede wiedergibt, wörtlich verwendet, ist es kein Zitat, denn die Phrase für sich hat keinen Sinn. Entweder

> Frau Merkel sagte: "Das ist business as usual."

oder

> Frau Merkel sagte, das sei business as usual.

Eine Ausnahme könnte allenfalls sein, wenn tatsächlich ein einzelnes Wort oder eine Phrase allein so bedeutsam wären, dass hervorgehoben werden soll, dass es wortwörtlich so gesagt wurde, etwa K. Müller-Hohenstein, die von der WM berichtete, es sei ihr ein innerer Reichsparteitag gewesen. Auch da macht der Kontext aber i.d.R. klar, dass es um die Formulierung geht, nicht das beschriebene Gefühl. Ob hier aber *business as usual* oder *Alltagsgeschäft, Normalität* wie von Janka nicht völlig illegitim vorgeschlagen wurde, verwendet wurde, ist völlig wumpe.

Die Anführungszeichen sind aber eine Marotte im Nachrichtengeschäft. Sie signalisieren eine Pseudoaccuratesse und sind daher sehr häufig.

Ein Lackmustest für die Verwendung von Anführungsstrichen ist, dass sich für das Zitat oder die direkte Rede die Erzählstimme ändert. Ist das sinnvoll, so stehen die Anführungsstriche zurecht.

Viele Menschen setzen, wie zur Warnung, alle Fremdwörter in Anführungsstriche. Typografisch sind Anführungsstriche eine Form der Hervorhebung, die den Lesefluss unterbrechen. Es gibt aber, zumal bei so gängigen Fremdwörtern, keinen Grund den Lesefluss zu zerhacken, sondern im Gegenteil. Sie helfen auch nicht beim Verstehen des Fremdwortes, weswegen sie wegzulassen sind. Eine Ausnahme könnte ein fremdsprachiges Wort sein, das auch im Deutschen vorkommt, aber etwas ganz anderes bedeutet. Als sehr konstruiertes Beispiel fällt mir nur sowas ein:

> Der englische Trainer feuerte die Mannschaft an, "fast" zu spielen.

Wo Kursivsetzung zur Verfügung steht, ist dies jedoch zu bevorzugen.

*Buisiness as usual* ist keine Aussage, von der interessant wäre, dass sie so wörtlich von Frau Merkel benutzt wurde, sondern nur ein Ausdruck, der für sich selbst gar nichts besagt und daher kein Zitat ist.

Ein unaufgeregtes Erklärvideo zu Gänsefüßchen findet sich bei [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/anfuhrungszeichen.php) (für Eilige, ab Minute 22 wird's heiß) und hier noch mehr zu [Zitaten und Konjunktiv](http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/konjunktiv/konjunktiv-obliquus.php).

Bei der Taz ist noch falsch (im Original nachgeschaut), dass es nicht *business als usual* heißen kann. Man zerpflückt generell keine Redewendung, um dann selektiv Partikel davon zu übersetzen. Die richtige Übersetzung wäre hier außerdem *wie* und nicht *als*, was nicht selten falsch gemacht wird im Deutschen und in Dialekten reihenweise. *Geschäfte wie üblich* würde aber wohl kaum jemand als *Geschäfte als üblich* wiedergeben, v.a. nicht in überregionalen Zeitungen. Womöglich aber ist es ein Aufmerksamkeitsfehler, der durch die Nähe von *as* und *als* begünstigt wurde (using sth. as sth. else/etwas als etwas anderes benutzen).

Bei der Groß-/Kleinschreibung kann ich nicht ganz so überzeugt Auskunft geben. Etablierte Fremdwörter werden wie deutsche Wörter behandelt.

> Ein Song rockte die Arena.

Das sind jedoch einzelne Wörter. *Ich bin up to date* würde ich aber insgesamt als Phrase kleinschreiben. Test: *Ich bin up to Date*. Als ikonisches Muster sollte die ganze Gruppe so geschrieben sein, wie man es gewohnt ist. Als integrierte Wortgruppe würde das *Date* nach Großschreibung verlangen, wie man auch schreibt, *ich bin auf dem Laufenden*. *Date* selbst wird im Deutschen auch als selbständiges Fremdwort benutzt, aber nur für Verabredung (ich habe ein Date). *Business* ist dagegen kein ständig benutzter Begriff im Alltag, wenn man von Geschäften spricht. Ausnahmen sind eng umgrenzte Verwendungen in Kombinationen wie *Businessclass*, oder *Businesslounge*, womöglich auch im Managerdeutsch als Jargon. 
Ich tendiere ästhetisch zur Klein- aber logisch zur Großschreibung und schließe mich im Fazit, weil ich keinen guten Grund dagegen habe, dem Duden an, also Kleinschreibung. Damit hätte nur die FAZ recht, welche auch als die sorgfältigste gilt, was die Sprache betrifft.

Answer (score -5):

All of these are bad because *business as usual* is far from being commonly understood. Germans have to know English well to know this phrase. Normal people know *business* but *as usual* decodes to NIL.

This phrase is used by *hohlgeblasene Eierköppe* who want to sound cosmopolitical and don't think before they write such *Stuss*.

The best replacements for *business as usual* are **Alltagsgeschäft**, **Alltag** or **Normalität**.

Comment: What do you mean with NIL?

Comment: *Tagesgeschäft* oder *zum Tagesgeschäft übergehen* sind einigermaßen etablierte Begriffe.

Comment: @Iris: NIL is nihil, nothing, null.

Comment: Für die meisten Leser von Taz, FAZ, SZ und womöglich der Webseite des Europ. Parlaments ist es sowohl eine gängige Phrase, als auch im Bereich ihrer Fremdsprachenkenntnisse.

Comment: Das bezweifle ich, so oft wie ich von diesen Leuten *round about* für *um die* zu hören bekomme. Das versteht kein Ami und auch die meisten Briten dürften eher an einen Kreisverkehr denken.

Comment: @Janka: Du hörst "round about" von Autoren der TAZ, FAZ, SZ und d. Webseite des EP?

Comment: Von Profen und sonstigen Intellektüllen. Selbes Klientel, welches auch meint, "business as usual" verwenden zu müssen.

Comment: Dies ist eine Antwort und sollte demnach nicht geflaggt werden.